# Google Drive + Meteor

Tags: meteor, google-drive-api

I'm planning on integrating some sort of realtime editing functionality in my tutoring app using Meteor. I've been using ShareJS till now, but I'd like to be able for users to edit spreadsheets and powerpoints as well as well as have more editing features. I've been thinking about how we could possibly integrate Google Drive's Docs,SpreadSheets, and Presentations interfaces into my API. Is this possible/legal using iFrames or is there any other format for doing so?

Comment: How are you using ShareJS?

Comment: i tried iframes, but their cross-origin policies prevent it. I'm getting somewhere with their [OAuth APIs](http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.files.list) though

Answer (score 0):

See their OAuth APIs for [drive.files.list](http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.files.list)..

It doesn't seem as integrated with the Meteor Auth as I'd like, but I'm getting somewhere with it.
After setting things up with `gapi.client.setApiKey`, then `gapi.auth.authorize` and `gapi.client.load`

`gapi.client.drive.files.list({}).execute( function(r){ console.log(r); } );`